# How to refresh if token has expired? API endpoint "/current" still used instead of "/anonymous" even though session has expired

Tags: session, spartacus-storefront

Even though the token has expired. Spartacus still uses "/users/current" instead of "/users/anonymous". Hence, we are getting HTTP 401 on the API calls.

We're using
"@spartacus/core": "^2.1.0",
"@spartacus/storefront": "^2.1.0",

Comment: Could you describe when exactly that happens? Is it the first of requests that gets 401 response?

Comment: If you leave the the user inactive for a few hours, then try to navigate to the page. There is no update if the user is now "logged out" due to inactivity to use 'anonymous' or is there an update happening on the background to update the user's session to remain as 'current'

Comment: If you use refresh_tokens then the token will be refreshed and the session will be continued. 
Without the refresh_token when the token expires every request that will respond with invalid token error will cause logout. It might have been the case for you that the particular request for user was the first request to initialize logout, but after that every request should be performed as anonymous user (not as current).

If you will find that there is particular problem with this api request please create github issue with more details how to reproduce.

Comment: Does that happen OOTB? We noticed there seems to be no OOTB functionality for this. Or did we miss anything? Where is this handled OOTB?

Comment: This functionality in version 2.x you can find in `AuthErrorInterceptor`